# Problem with adduser over SSH script depending on OS distro

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ssh, scripting

Hi this script is saying there is an issue at:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash: -c: line 0: `sudo -i if sudo cat /etc/*-release | grep Ubuntu; then echo "Ubuntu Server";'
```

But I cant see whats wrong with the syntax

```
#!/bin/bash -x




echo Enter server IP:
read server

scp /home/Zenoss/.ssh/authorized_keys ******@$server:/home/******

sshpass -p ********  ssh -t ******@$server sudo -i 'if sudo cat /etc/*-release | grep Ubuntu; then echo "Ubuntu Server";
sudo groupadd --gid 7000 zenoss;
sudo adduser --uid 7000 --gid 7000 --disabled-password --gecos "" zenoss;
sudo mkdir /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo mv /home/******/authorized_keys /home/zenoss/.ssh/;
sudo chmod 700 /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo chmod 600 /home/zenoss/.ssh/authorized_keys;
sudo chown -R zenoss /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo chgrp -R zenoss /home/zenoss/.ssh;
fi;

if sudo cat /etc/*-release | grep CENTOS; then echo "Centos Server";
sudo groupadd --gid 7000 zenoss;
sudo useradd -u 7000 -g 7000 zenoss;
sudo mkdir /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo mv /home/******/authorized_keys /home/zenoss/.ssh/;
sudo chmod 700 /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo chmod 600 /home/zenoss/.ssh/authorized_keys;
sudo chown -R zenoss /home/zenoss/.ssh;
sudo chgrp -R zenoss /home/zenoss/.ssh;
fi;

if sudo getenforce | grep Enforcing; then echo "SElinux is enforcing"; else echo "Selinux is not enforcing"; fi;
if sudo getenforce | grep Enforcing; then sudo restorecon -R -v /home/zenoss/.ssh; fi;
exit'
```

Any help will be massively appreciated.

Comment: You can't just put arbitrary shell syntax in `sudo`. Try `sudo -i bash -c 'the rest of your script'` and see how that goes. On a different note, there is probably a more general way to do this so you can support more OSs without hardcoding them all

Comment: @Fox that didnt work but I managed to get it working by changing the script to 'sudo -i; rest of script' rather than sudo -i 'rest of script'

Comment: Note the `bash -c`.  If you replace it with `sudo -i; rest of script`, it will run `sudo -i`, wait for end of input, then run the rest of the script.  I'm not sure that is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by changing the script to 'sudo -i; rest of script' rather than sudo -i 'rest of script'